# mi ventana en pyhton con tkinter no me muestra datos de mi base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos

tengo una ventana con una tabla en la cual quiero mostrar informacion de la base datos, estoy usando sqlite3, en codigo no me da error pero no me muestra los valores que quiero, no entiendo porque creo que estoy asignando mal las columnas, si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria sou nuevo en este mundo,a cntinuacion dejo el codigo:

```css
import tkinter as tk     #importo librerias utiles
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3


class VentanaInformacion(tk.Toplevel):

 # conecto con BD , nombro y creo funcion 
    bd_nombre = "Basededatosregistro.db"   
    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        super().__init__(window)
        self.geometry("2000x800")
        self.config(background='#4BC0EB') 
        self.title("INFORMACION")  
        self.fondo2=PhotoImage(file="Recurso 21800.gif")
        tk.Label(self, image=self.fondo2).  place(x=-1, y=0)
        self.create_widgets()

    def fNuevo(self):         
        pass
    
    def fGuardar(self):        
        pass
                 
    def fModificar(self):        
        pass
    
    def fEliminar(self):
        passZA

    def fCancelar(self):
        pass

    def create_widgets(self):
        frame1 = Frame(self, bg="#bfdaff") #primer frame
        frame1.place(x=0,y=0,width=400, height=1100) 
        self.frame1=PhotoImage(file="FRAMEE.gif")
        lbl = Label(frame1, image=self.frame1).  place(x=0, y=0)

        self.btnNuevo=Button(frame1,text="Nuevo", command=self.fNuevo, bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=7, font=("Times New Roman", 30)) 
        self.btnNuevo.place(x=55, y=350, width=300,  height=100)  

        self.btnModificar=Button(frame1,text="Modificar", command=self.fModificar, bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=7, font=("Times New Roman", 30)) 
        self.btnModificar.place(x=55,y=500, width=300,  height=100)     

        self.btnEliminar=Button(frame1,text="Eliminar", command=self.fEliminar, bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=7, font=("Times New Roman", 30)) 
        self.btnEliminar.place(x=55,y=650, width=300,  height=100)  

#frame 2  para llenar registro
        frame2 = Frame(self,bg="#d3dde3" )
        frame2.place(x=400,y=0,width=400, height=1100)         
        self.frame2=PhotoImage(file="FRAMEE.gif")
        lbl = Label(frame2, image=self.frame2).  place(x=0, y=0)              
            
        lbl1 = Label(frame2,text=" NOMBRES ", font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") .place(x=40,y=100)     
        self.txtISO3=Entry(frame2, fg="#3B96B8", font=("Times New Roman", 20)) .place(x=40,y=150) 

        lbl2 = Label(frame2,text=" ESPECIALIDAD ", font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") .place(x=40,y=250)   
        self.txtName=Entry(frame2,  fg="#3B96B8", font=("Times New Roman", 20)) .place(x=40,y=300) 


        lbl3 = Label(frame2,text="HORARIOS",font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") .place(x=40,y=400)    
        self.txtCapital=Entry(frame2,  fg="#3B96B8", font=("Times New Roman", 20)) .place(x=40,y=450)  

        lbl4 = Label(frame2,text="TELEFONO ", font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") .place(x=40,y=550)    
        self.txtCurrency=Entry(frame2, fg="#3B96B8", font=("Times New Roman", 20)) .place(x=40,y=600)  

        lbl5 = Label(frame2,text=" DISPONIBLE ", font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") .place(x=40,y=700)    
        self.txtCurrency=Entry(frame2, fg="#3B96B8", font=("Times New Roman", 20)) .place(x=40,y=750)  
            
            #BOTONES LIMPIAR Y GUARDAR 

        self.btnGuardar=Button(frame2,text="Guardar", command=self.fGuardar, font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") 
        self.btnGuardar.place(x=30,y=850,width=150, height=50)

        self.btnCancelar=Button(frame2,text="Cancelar", command=self.fCancelar, font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") 
        self.btnCancelar.place(x=220,y=850,width=150, height=50) 

        self.botonsalir1= tk.Button(self, text='Regresar')
        self.botonsalir1.config(background='#011B61', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=7, font=("Times New Roman", 40), command=self.destroy)
        self.botonsalir1.place(x=60,  y=800, width=290,  height=120) 
           
#REALIZO LA TABLAS CON TREEVIEW 

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=("col1","col2","col3","col4"))  
            # configuarar columnas       
        self.tree.column("#0",width=30)
        self.tree.column("col1",width=30, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("col2",width=30, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("col3",width=30, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("col4",width=30, anchor=CENTER)   
            #les coloco nombres 
        self.tree.heading("#0", text="NOMBRES", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("col1", text="ESPECIALIDAD", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("col2", text="HORARIOS", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("col3", text="TELEFONO", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("col4", text="DISPONIBLE", anchor=CENTER)        
        self.tree.place(x=800,y=0,width=1150, height=1000)


        self.get_INFORMACION()
#realizo conexion 
    def consulta_eje(self, query, parameters = ()): # recibo parametros de consulta, ejecutara los mismos codigos siempre que se interactue con la Bd
        with sqlite3.connect(self.bd_nombre) as conec:   #conecto con la base de datos y guardo la coneccion como conec
            cursor = conec.cursor()  #metodo cursor para obtener la posicion de la base de datos y lo guardo en una variable curso
            resultado = cursor.execute(query, parameters) #permite ejecutar una consulta sql
            conec.commit() # ejecuto cada vez que quiera operar con la bd 
        return resultado # retorno el resultado 

    def get_INFORMACION(self): # Creo una funcion para trae la informacio  de la base de datos 
        registros =  self.tree.get_children()  #obtengo todos los datos de la tabla para limpio la tabla o agregar 
        for element in registros:
            self.tree.delete(element) 
        query = "SELECT * FROM INFORMACION ORDER BY NOMBRE ASC"  # consulto datos de LA TABLA Y PIDO EL ORDEN para pasarla a consulta
        filas_bd= self.consulta_eje(query) #me devuleve las filas de BD 
        for row in filas_bd :  #para cada fila 
            self.tree.insert("col1", text = row["col2"], values = row["col3"] )
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = VentanaInformacion(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

cree la base de datos y se encuentra en la misma carpeta en la que estpy trabajando toda la informacion de la ventana , se creo bien y correctamente, ahora bien, no se si la conexion se este haciendo, como podria verificar uso manjaro.